# Complete new installation of App instead of 'update' in iOs appstore?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, keychain

Ok so this is the case. I overtook the iOS development of an app from another developer and the app is using keychains in oder to save the username and password.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827963/values-that-i-put-in-keychain-can-be-saved-after-app-is-updated) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html) the keychains won't be affected if you use the same 'provisioning profile' for distributing your application.

Now the problem is, I do not have the 'provisioning profile' from the last developer and I already published the application on store.... as expected, those users who updated the app cannot use the app until they completely reinstall the app (since the keychains need to be reseted).

now my question is, what's the solution now? I can somehow find the last guy's 'provisioning profile' used for the app but then the customers need to wait for 5-6 days to see changes since the stupid apple review takes long time and I'm not even 100% sure if it's gonna 100% work.

also if I do that, the new users who already de-installed and re-installed the app will face problems again since I will change to the old `provisioning profile and they will get affected.

Is there any way to **FORCE** the app to completely de-install and re-install instead of an update??

any other suggestions are also more than welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Have you transferred app from one developer account to another developer account?

Comment: It's actually on the same account tbh but the problem is that he used some old provisioning profiles which I think he already deleted since I don't see it in the member center.

Comment: Just try to create new provisioning profile with new .csr file (if you don't have older one) in this case.

Comment: Yes I did create new provisioning profiles, but the keychain values somehow are not working properly and you get an empty value after I did that.

Comment: In the link which I posed above it's explicitly saying "Note: On iPhone, Keychain rights depend on the provisioning profile used to sign your application. Be sure to consistently use the same provisioning profile across different versions of your application."

Comment: Please let me know that, have you created new csr file or used older one?

Comment: Now that I checked you are right. I have used old .csr and certificates all in general. So are you saying that's the problem? Like if I create new provisioning profiles and new certificates from scratch the next update would work?

Comment: Most probably. I am not sure, but try to use new csr file and create new provisioning profiles and use that newly generated provisioning profile.

Comment: I will give that a try... takes some few days cause you know... the reviews -.- Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Dhruv I totally forgot about this question, Yes I recreated all the provision profiles and it worked! You can answer this question and I'll mark your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to create new provisioning profile with new .csr file (if you don't have older one) in this case.

This will solve your problem.